# How to safely store password in a PHP session (for re-usage against an API)

Tags: php, session, encryption, zend-framework, password-protection

**Situation:**

I have two systems, a Java-API requiring user/password checking credentials against LDAP and a frontend for that API written in PHP. The frontend probably needs to store the user/password combination in a session.

**Suggestion:**

I would use a block cipher implementation like Zend\Crypt (<2.5) [1] with AES and use simple PHP sessions (probably file based).

**Question:**

1.) Is encryption of the password the only choice?

2.) What encryption/mode would you suggest regarding a good compromise between safety and speed

Password hashing is NOT an option because the API requires the plain password.

[1] https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.crypt.block-cipher.html

Comment: a better alternative is to use oauth2 instead of the username/password pair.

sending username/password in every request even if encrypted causes  security issues

Comment: you dont need original password, just hash

Comment: Also you can use JSON Web Token - https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: I can't just hash the password, because the last chain requires the plain password.

Comment: Do you have any choice here to use something other than a plaintext password? Get an LDAP token or something? Or must your frontend hold onto the plaintext password to use the backend (in which case: what a terrible backend)?